# Chosen plug-in is not working when i create the element dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

Chosen plug-in is not working when i create the element dynamically

i created Select list dynamically from ajax response and the problem is Chosen plug-in not working with it , Please help me to solve it

here is my code:

```
function GetSubCategories(ID) {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: '/Home/GetSubCategoriesByAjax',
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'Json',
        data: { id: ID },

        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                console.log(data)


                $("#SubListSelect").empty();
                var $SubListSelect = $('<select id ="SubListSelect" class = "form-control"></select>');
                $SubListSelect.append('<option>Select Sub Category</option>');
                $.each(data, function (i, value) {



                    $SubListSelect.append('<option value=' + value.SubCategoryId + '>' + value.SubCategoryName + '</option>');
                });

                $("#Div1").empty();
                $("#Div1").append($SubListSelect);


            }
            else {

            }
        },
        error: function (r) {
            alert('Error! Please try again.');
            console.log(r);

        }
    });

}
```

and and plugin code:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {


        $(function () {
            $("#SubListSelect").chosen();
        });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proposal:

in my demo I used a different url for the ajax and I figured out a possible HTML.

```js
function GetSubCategories(ID) {
  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: "https://api.github.com/users",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    data: { id: ID },
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.length > 0) {
        var SubListSelect = $('<select id ="SubListSelect" class = "form-control"></select>')
        .append('<option>Select Sub Category</option>');
        $.each(data, function (i, value) {
          SubListSelect.append('<option value=' + value.id + '>' + value.login + '</option>');
        });
        $("#Div1").empty().append(SubListSelect);
        $("#Div1").find(SubListSelect).chosen()
      } else {
      }
    },
    error: function (r) {
      alert('Error! Please try again.');
      console.log(r);

    }
  });
}
$(document).ready(function ($) {
  $("#SubListSelect").chosen();
  $('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
    GetSubCategories('1');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<!--
The next two lines are the include files for chosen plugin
-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="Div1">
This is the starting div:
</div>
<button id="btn">Click Me To Create New chosen object into DIV</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it says  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).chosen is not a function

Comment: Thank you , but the error comes from 
$("#Div1").find($SubListSelect).chosen()

Comment: @Lucy This error means the chosen library has not been included. So, check the library.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `select` is in `#Div1` which you are emptying, then re-appending.

in that case you need to re-initialize it:-

```
$("#Div1").empty();
$("#Div1").append($SubListSelect);
$("#SubListSelect").chosen();
```

A better option though would be to only empty the select and re-append the options to the select without emptying the `#Div1`. then call:-

```
$("#SubListSelect").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

also, this

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
```

and this

```
$(function () {
```

mean the same thing, with the latter being short hand. Therefore you only need one.